# SQL IDENTITY autoincrement when 0 but still allow explicit inserts

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am dealing with this problem: I would like to have autogenerated identity in my table which is of type int

But, I would like to be able to explicitly set the identity. Now the real challenge is that this stuff is going through Entity Framework. I have my database with a `IDENTITY(1,1)` column, and `IDENTITY_INSERT` set to `ON`.

And whenever the `Id` is 0 (not specified) in newly created object, it inserts the very same 0. Any help appreciated, except offers to reconsider architecture (I will do that in any other case if this attempt fails).

And all this must work either on SQL CE, and SQL Server.

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact problem is you're trying to solve. Can you provide a use case of why and when you would want to insert a defined ID rather than an auto incremented ID?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?  It sounds like using a `Sequence` might make more sense than using an identity column.

Comment: `Id is 0 (not specified)` 0 is the default and perfectly valid value for an int, so it IS specified. Try making `Id` nullable. If it's null (as opposed to 0) EF should be able to take care of it.

Comment: Why bother with setting the identity property if you are going to define the value anyway? That doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: The problem I am solving is: in most cases the autoincrement is the thing I need, but in cases where I have to restore item from "archive" table to the "live" table requires the same ID as it was before. I hope this makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

If you tell EF the primary key is database generated then it will not pass the id to the insert sql.  You need to pass the ID so go with `DatabaseGenerated.None`.

But you want it to be an IDENTITY, so make it one in a migration script. You could change the `CREATETABLE` statement, adding `identity: true` to the column specification, or you can modify the table by running sql using the `Sql()` method

Now you need to modify the actual sql run during insert. The only way to do that is [configure your model to use stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx) then modify the sql generated in the Up migration for the insert procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[My_Insert]  
  @Id int,  
  --ETC  
AS  
BEGIN 
  IF(Id > 0) SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON

  INSERT --ETC

  IF(Id > 0) THEN BEGIN
     SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF
     SELECT Id
  ELSE
     SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS Id 
  END

END
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer, one thing i did forgot to mention - it needs to work on both sql server and sql ce so procedure is not an option.

Comment: That's some catch, that Catch-22....if you override `SaveChanges` then you might be able to substitute your own sql in there, but I would look at changing the way you archive and restore